# Array_merge() - trying to unserialize session variable as first argument throws error

Tags: php, html

I get this error:

```
"Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\sam\arraysession.php on line 16"
```

but the irony is this example is from the book...
And there is no typing mistake, I checked it a few times. 
Can someone give me a tip? I'm really frustrated...

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <title>Storing an array with a session</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Product choice page</h1>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['form_products'])) {
            if(!empty($_SESSION['products'])) {
                echo $_SESSION['products'];
                $products = array_unique(
                array_merge(unserialize($_SESSION['products']), $_POST['form_products']));
            } else {
                $_SESSION['products'] = $_POST['form_products'];
            }
        echo "<p>Your products have been registered!</p>";
        }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <p><label for="form_products">Select some products:</label><br>
        <select id="form_products" name="form_products[]" multiple="multiple"
        size = "3">
        <option value="Sonic Screwdriver">Sonic screwdriver</option>
        <option value="Hal 2000">Hal 2000</option>
        <option value="Tardis">Tardis</option>
        <option value="ORAC">ORAC</option>
        <option value="Transporter bracelet">Transporter bracelet</option>
        </select></p>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="choose">Submit form</button>
    </form>
    <p><a href="session1.php">go to content page</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

$_SESSION['products'] contains

```
a:3:{i:0;s:17:"Sonic Screwdriver";i:1;s:8:"Hal 2000";i:2;s:6:"Tardis";}
```

var_dump $_SESSION['products'] shows

```
string(71) "a:3:{i:0;s:17:"Sonic Screwdriver";i:1;s:8:"Hal 2000";i:2;s:6:"Tardis";}"
```

unserialize($_SESSION['products']); contains

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sonic Screwdriver
    [1] => Hal 2000
    [2] => Tardis
)
```

Comment: put `var_dump(unserialize($_SESSION['products']));` before your array merge. What does it give?

Comment: what is that unserialize doing in there? there is no serialization there to begin with

Comment: Replace `echo $_SESSION['products'];` with `print_r($_SESSION['products'])` and show use the result ( edit the question, dont add it as a comment)

Comment: @Ghost How do you know what has previously been put into the `$_SESSION['products']`

Comment: @mithunsatheesh , it says: NULL.

Comment: @RiggsFolly echo $_SESSION['products']; outputs only this: N.

Comment: Sorry I edited out my mistake take another look at that comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried to edit my comment but i cant click on a "pencil". Anyway,this is what I get after your suggestion:

a:3:{i:0;s:17:"Sonic Screwdriver";i:1;s:8:"Hal 2000";i:2;s:6:"Tardis";}string(71) "a:3:{i:0;s:17:"Sonic Screwdriver";i:1;s:8:"Hal 2000";i:2;s:6:"Tardis";}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are unserializing the `$_SESSION['products']`, it is expected to contain a string. So while you store the values into it, store the serailized form of posted array.

You have to do like

```
if (isset($_POST['form_products'])) {
    if(!empty($_SESSION['products'])) {
        $products = array_unique(
        array_merge(unserialize($_SESSION['products']), $_POST['form_products']));
        $_SESSION['products'] = serialize($products);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['products'] = serialize($_POST['form_products']);
    }
    echo "<p>Your products have been registered!</p>";
}
```

Comment: @BoraManasijevic : you have to unset the existing value in `$_SESSION['products']` first then try this script. else you will get error

Comment: Thank you man, it does work! I cannot believe how it is possible that example in book containts flaws ...

Comment: @BoraManasijevic : see the update at `$_SESSION['products'] = serialize($products);`. You have to set the products variable to session. else the earlier value will be overwritten.